# Trouble changing toggle value from active to not active

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, semantic-ui

### Background

I have added a toggle button in my Redux app that allows someone to toggle whether they like a specific tv show or not. When I click the button once, I can toggle it on (make the button active), but when I click it again the value does not revert back to its original value (the button is not active).

### What I've Already Tried

The semantic-ui-react documentation gives [an example of usuage](https://react.semantic-ui.com/elements/button/#variations-toggle), but I am not sure how to incorporate this logic into my current code since I am already using a handleWatchlist callback for another change to state.

I know the problem lies in the way I am handling the value being passed to the active property of my button. Here, I am passing watchlistValue which is always either true or false.

```
        <Popup
           trigger={
               <Button
                 toggle
                 active={watchlistValue}
                 onClick={(_) => this.handleWatchlist(programId, 
                   watchlistValue)} 
                 icon='heart'
                      />}
            content="Add to Watchlist."
            size='tiny'/>
```

Here is my current handleWatchlist method.

```
handleWatchlist = (programId, watchlistValue) => {

    this.props.toggleWatchlist(programId, watchlistValue)

  }
```

Here is how I have defined the program whose watchlist value (the heart button) I wish to toggle.

```
let program = this.props.program ? this.props.program : this.props.programs[this.props.match.params.id - 1]

let programId = this.props.program ? this.props.program.id : null

let watchlistValue = this.props.program ? this.props.program.watchlist : null
```

*Here is a link to the [whole file](https://github.com/koberlander/tv-list-frontend/blob/master/src/components/programs/Program.js) if you need to see the all on one page.*

The toggle function already updates the value of my watchlist item in the database. In the DOM, clicking it makes it go active once. Unfortunately, it will not toggle off (to a false value).

#### Thank you in advance for your time and please let me know if I need to provide additional details.

Comment: If you have commented `mapStateToProps `, then how you are passing the props?

Comment: @ravibagul91 I passed down the program props from a parent container. In this component, I am using connect() to have access to those props. Here is the parent file if that helps. https://github.com/koberlander/tv-list-frontend/blob/master/src/components/programs/Programs.js

Comment: Looks like a fun project. I've got it running locally but the add program button isn't working so I can't get the toggle button to appear. Do you have some test data or something that isn't in your github repo to get some shows in the list?

Comment: @Paddy My apologies for not seeing this note while I was away for my computer so that I could provide more clarity. I appreciate that you went above and beyond to search through my repo, even when you did not have to. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your reducer change

```
let programToBeToggled = copyOfPrograms.find(program => program.id === action.id);
programToBeToggled.watchlist = !action.watchlist;
```

to

```
let programIndex = copyOfPrograms.findIndex(program => program.id === action.id);
copyOfPrograms[programIndex].watchlist = !copyOfPrograms[programIndex].watchlist;
```

copyOfPrograms.find is creating a new object which you are toggling the watchList value of. However that does not change the boolean in copyOfPrograms which you are then returning from the reducer.

Full case with console logs to help spot bug:

```
case 'TOGGLE_WATCHLIST':

    /*
        Make a deep copy of our current state by using JSON.stringify to turn our array of programs into a string.
        After we have created the stringifiedPrograms, we then use JSON.parse to turn it back into a brand new array of objects.
        We then take our copyOfPrograms and find the specific program that we want to update (here we find it by id).
        After isolating that program, we update the value of watchlist.
        Then we return a copy of state, with the program key set to our copyOfPrograms array of objects.
        Updating my programToBeToggled watchlist value still updates it in the copyOfPrograms array.
    */
    console.log('state.programs:');
    console.log(state.programs);

    let stringifiedPrograms = JSON.stringify(state.programs);
    console.log('stringifiedPrograms:');
    console.log(stringifiedPrograms);

    let copyOfPrograms = JSON.parse(stringifiedPrograms);
    console.log('copyOfPrograms:');
    console.log(copyOfPrograms);

    let programIndex = copyOfPrograms.findIndex(program => program.id === action.id);
    copyOfPrograms[programIndex].watchlist = !copyOfPrograms[programIndex].watchlist;
    console.log('copyOfPrograms after switcheroo:');
    console.log(copyOfPrograms);

    return {...state, programs: copyOfPrograms};
```

Comment: This works!!! Thank you for adding in the console.logs so I could follow along. Additionally, 'copyOfPrograms after switcheroo' made me laugh and it is 100% staying. I made tons of notes based on your feedback so that I remember how to solve this type of thing in the future! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your action is missing the `watchlist` key, leading the toggle value to always be `true`.

From `actions/toggleWatchlist.js`:

```
    // dispatched action has a `type` and an `id`
    .then(res => dispatch({type: 'TOGGLE_WATCHLIST', id: programId}))
```

from `reducers/programReducer.js`:

```
    // action.watchlist is undefined so !action.watchlist is always true
    programToBeToggled.watchlist = !action.watchlist
```

Be careful with when and where you're toggling the values as well, you should only toggle them once, either in the action or the reducer so make sure you don't fix the above issue only to toggle in both action and reducer, negating the toggle.